# why is this setOnTouchListener for SurfaceView but onTouch for Activity

Tags: android, view, surfaceview, ontouchlistener, ontouch

So I have followed this tutorial and the code works perfectly. However I have some trouble understanding how OnTouchListener and OnTouch work together. I have spent a long time trauling this forum, websites and documentation to understand but still, I do not.

In this code, a OnTouchListener is set for ourSurfaceView, and then the onTouch is called for the activity?!

Can someone please explain the relationship of OnTouchListener and OnTouch across different activities and views. Many Thanks!

```
package com.games.michael.waterproofme;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    MySurface ourSurfaceView;
    float x,y,sX, sY, fX, fY;
    Bitmap test, plus;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ourSurfaceView = new MySurface(this);
        ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
        x = 0;
        y = 0;
        sX = 0;
        sY = 0;
        fX = 0;
        fY = 0;
        test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sportsball);//draw ball
        plus = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.plus);
        setContentView(ourSurfaceView);
    }

@Override
protected  void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ourSurfaceView.pause();
}

@Override
protected  void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ourSurfaceView.resume();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();

    switch(event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            sX = event.getX();
            sY = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            fX = event.getX();
            fY = event.getY();
            break;
    }

    return true;//false = finished dont loop through. true = loop through
}

public class MySurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = false;

    public MySurface(Context context){
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    public void pause(){
        isRunning = false;
        while(true){
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread = null;
    }

    public void resume(){
        isRunning = true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    public void run() {
        while(isRunning){
            if(!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {/
                continue;}
            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
            if (x != 0 && y != 0){
                canvas.drawBitmap(test, x-(test.getWidth()/2), y-(test.getHeight()/2), null);//bitmap, left, top, paint
            }
            if (sX != 0 && sY != 0){
                canvas.drawBitmap(plus, sX-(plus.getWidth()/2), sY-(plus.getHeight()/2), null);//bitmap, left, top, paint
            }
            if (fX != 0 && fY != 0){
                canvas.drawBitmap(plus, fX-(plus.getWidth()/2), fY-(plus.getHeight()/2), null);//bitmap, left, top, paint
            }
            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`OnTouchListener` is interface - class that implements it must override its methods. For `android.view.View.OnTouchListener` this is one method: `boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)`

When touch event occurs in your `SurfaceView` there is check if onTouchListener is set and if so its `onTouch` method is called

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please explain the relationship of OnTouchListener and OnTouch across different activities and views.

Touch events on views are invoked if you register any callback to them. SurfaceView extends the View class.

> ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);
>
> setContentView(ourSurfaceView);

So you just set the **ourSurfaceView** to the activity as their content view and registered the **View.OnTouchListener**. That means the abstract method onTouch is invoked on the **ourSurfaceView** instance and not the activity.

> In this code, a OnTouchListener is set for ourSurfaceView, and then the onTouch is called for the activity?!

No, it delegates any touch event from **ourSurfaceView** instance as their content view to your **MainActivity** class because you registered the **View.OnTouchListener**

Just a simple Java example:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args){
    SurfaceClass surfaceClass = new SurfaceClass();
    ActivityClass activityClass = new ActivityClass();
    surfaceClass.setOnFartListener(activityClass);

    //Touch event :D
    surfaceClass.fart();
}

public static class ActivityClass implements SurfaceClass.OnFartListener{

    @Override
    public void onFart(String kindOfFart) {
        System.out.println(kindOfFart);
    }
}

public static class SurfaceClass{

    private SurfaceClass.OnFartListener onFartListener;

    public void fart(){
        if(onFartListener != null){
            onFartListener.onFart("Huge One!!");
        }
    }

    public void setOnFartListener(SurfaceClass.OnFartListener onFartListener){
        this.onFartListener = onFartListener;
    }

    public interface OnFartListener{

        void onFart(String kindOfFart);

    }
}}
```

See touch event below :D

```
javac Main.java && java Main
```